# About the Workload type option of PostgreSQL Flexible server

Tags: postgresql, azure

I use Azure Database for PostgreSQL to build a DB environment.
I would like to ask the following questions regarding the Workload type selection items.
When selecting Production (Large-size), there was a description of availability, but when selecting Production (Small / Medium-size), there was no description of availability.
In fact, both have availability options, but why isn't availability mentioned in the Production (Small / Medium-size) description?

What is the specific difference between Production (Large-size) and Production (Small / Medium-size)?

I am looking forward to your answer. thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What did Azure tell you when you asked them? They know the answer, it's their product.